# What is wrong in my code if all my if statements are being ignored?

Tags: python, while-loop, menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sehMD.png)
I am a begginer and don't know what I've done wrong, help.

I tried multiple things, but all didn't work.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of things going wrong here. You have declared a variable p as integer type with `p=0`, yet you use it like a bool in the while loop and you are trying to use it like a string input in the `if else` statements. Consider using more variables for your purpose.

First, replace `p=0` with `p=True`. Let this be your loop flag.

Second, inside the loop, make a new variable say q.
`q = int(input(`Your text here`))`

Third, for the if else condition, since we have an integer type q, do this:

```
if q == 1:
    print('You selected 1.')
elif q == 2:
    print('You selected 2.') #and so on
```

Ultimately your code might look something like this:

```
def menu():
    p = True
    while p:
        q = int(input('Enter the value:'))
        if q == 1:
            print('You selected 1')
        elif q == 2:
            print('You selected 2')
        elif q == 3:
            print('You selected 3')

menu()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use while True, equivalent to what you wrote. You can use a list with the values ​​​​that you need, and if your entered information is in that list, then we display the entered information, and if not, then again

```
def menu3():
    while True:
        q = int(input('*you text 1* '))
        q_true = [1, 2, 3]
        if q in q_true:
            print(f'*you text 2* {q}')

menu3()
```